# Get formatted values from a multi-cell range

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim myText As String
myText= Range("a3").Text
```

Returns the formatted value in cell A3, but

```
myText= Range("a3:c7").Text
```

gives me an error.

How do I get strings representing formatted values from a multi-cell range, while preserving the number format? i.e. the format of the output text would be the same as if copy-pasting from the range to a text editor.

Comment: Note: you can either get the visible formatted result in the cell using .Text, or you can get the underlying unformatted value from the cell using .Value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to get multiple cell values into an array with one single statement (no loops) is with a Variant array.

```
Dim varItemName As Variant
varItemName = Range("a3:c7")
```

If you really absolutely need the names to be type `String`, then just `CStr` them later when you use them.

```
output = FunctionRequiringStringArgument(CStr(varItemName(1,2))
```

---

**EDIT**: Okay, okay, you want strings with same format as in sheet.

Here's a full working example.

```
Dim strMyFormat1 As String
Dim varItemName As Variant
Dim strItemName() As String
Dim strItemNameBF() As String
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim rngMyRange As Range

Set rngMyRange = Range("A3:C7")
varItemName = rngMyRange
ReDim strItemName(LBound(varItemName, 1) To UBound(varItemName, 1), _
    LBound(varItemName, 2) To UBound(varItemName, 2))

'// Take a sample of the format
strMyFormat1 = Range("A3").NumberFormat

'// Apply format sample to all values
For iRow = LBound(varItemName, 1) To UBound(varItemName, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varItemName, 2) To UBound(varItemName, 2)
        strItemName(iRow, iCol) = Format(varItemName(iRow, iCol), strMyFormat1)
    Next iCol
Next iRow
'// Can also apply to only some values -- adjust loops.
'// More loops go here if many format samples.

'// If all cells have different formats, must use brute force -- slower.
ReDim strItemNameBF(1 To rngMyRange.Rows.Count, _
    1 To rngMyRange.Columns.Count)
For iRow = 1 To rngMyRange.Rows.Count
    For iCol = 1 To rngMyRange.Columns.Count
        strItemNameBF(iRow, iCol) = rngMyRange.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

Comment: The format of the output text being as for example while we would get while copying from the range and pasting in a notepad.

Comment: Edited answer to address this. I guess I got confused by the double "while".

Answer (score 6):

```
For Each c In Range("a3:c7")
    ItemName = c.Text
Next c
```

This will give you each cell one after the other.

Comment: If you have a large data set then looping through the range is incredibly slow. But just for a few cells it works. Also, using .Text can cut off some of your information since it only returns what the user sees.

Comment: I got a down vote ????? OK, in my opinion this is the perfect, Excel build in solution to visit every cell in a range (for a small amount of cells). From the OP I don't know what he wants to do with the data. So the example in the question is about 15 cells ==> perfect solution. I know it is not fast to loop through cells. If there are large amount of datasets then load the Data into the memory (see Jean-Francois Corbetts answer). I personally work on my Data (~ 40000 large Datasets) using Perl and use Excel only for analyses and visualization.

Answer (score 5):

This is a modified version of one of the post here and it worked for me.

```
    Function Range2Text(ByVal my_range As Range) As String
        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
        Dim v1 As Variant
        Dim Txt As String

        v1 = my_range
        For i = 1 To UBound(v1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(v1, 2)
                Txt = Txt & v1(i, j)
            Next j
            Txt = Txt & vbCrLf
        Next i

        Range2Text = Txt
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a collection and run through all the Areas of the range and collect the text into 
the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim i as integer, j as integer
Dim v1 as variant

v1=range("a3:c7")

for i=1 to ubound(v1)
  for j=1 to ubound(v1,2)
    debug.print v1(i,j)
  next j
next i
```

Comment: This solution doesn't include the formatting that is required in question. This just extracts the value of the cells.