# Display selected range of cells in Textbox1

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing an issue while trying to display a selected range of cells from Excel to a UserForm textbox, say `C1:E14.` The code below is giving me an `Runtime error '13' Type Mismatch`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim SelRange As Range
Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
Set SelRange = Selection
Range("TABLE").Select
Application.Goto "TABLE"
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Range("C1:E14").Value
'UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Range("C1:E14").Select
End Sub
```

If I use `.Value` it's giving the above mentioned error, but if I use `.Select "True"` it is printing in the UserForm text box.

Comment: That's a range of 42 individual cells ... what do you want in the text box? all of them? delimited/displayed how?

Comment: A similar question and discussion  from the past:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590963/get-text-from-a-cell-range-in-excel-vba

Comment: To sum it up, you cannot use the `Value` (or `Text`) property of a `Range` object that contains more than one cell, unless you assign it to a variable of type `Variant` (because it's an array).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct. You are trying to set a range to a string.

you can turn it into a range using something like this

```
Public Function Join(seperator As String, rng As Variant) As String

    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim joinedString As String
    For Each cell In rng
        joinedString = joinedString & cell & seperator
    Next cell
    joinedString = Left(joinedString, Len(joinedString) - Len(seperator))
    Join = joinedString

End Function
```

Then

`UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Join(",",Range("C1:E14"))`

or if you want to make new lines out of each cell

```
Dim joinedString as string
joinedString  = Join("|",Range("C1:E14"))
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Replace(joinedString  , "|", vbCrLf)
```

Comment: In versions 2019+/MSExcel365 this can be replaced by e.g. `Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Textjoin(vbNewline,False,Sheet1.Range("C1:E14"))`